# How do I debug SSLHandshakeException and find the root cause?

Tags: java, ssl, https, cloudflare

I maintain a Java Swing Desktop application that intermittently doesn't work for individual users with the following SSL network error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The issue is not reproducible for me, nor the vast majority of end users, and seems to be specific to individual users, and pops up repeatedly every other month for one user or another. It's rarely the same user twice. It's very mysterious.

The application is running on the latest JDK 17 and the requested HTTPS resource is served via an CloudFlare edge cache.

Googling the error message would suggest a root certificate issue, but the application has its own private JDK runtime, so it should work the same for all users. Notably, users report that the issue appears out of nowhere after using the application without problems for months.

How would I go about debugging the issue? Are there any system properties or JDK logger options that I can use to make the application log more information on end-user machines that would allow me to identify the root cause where the SSL back-and-forth goes awry?

Comment: If this message is specific to individual users it might be caused by SSL interception at their end. SSL interception replaces the certificate which makes it not trusted for the application - unless the CA from the interceptor is explicitly added as trusted.  SSL interception happens often in corporate environments but also in several local antivirus in order to detect attacks even in encrypted communication.

Comment: For what it's worth: there is a log feature using [sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-31B7E142-B874-46E9-8DD0-4E18EC0EB2CF) (possibly add `:trustmanager` if it appears not to be using the correct truststore) (the colons aren't required but help readability). This will produce _lots_ of output, which must be kept secure because it contains key-gen info that would enable a wiretapper to decrypt your/your user's protected data. Is that risk worth it? Your call.